# Why does the 'Apps' tab show hot questions and the 'Scripts' tab high scoring questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-deferred, meta

The Stack Apps homepage has two unique tabs which are not present on other sites: [Apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) and [Scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps). There is a slight difference between the two, which is visible upon hovering:

[image]

[image]

That's right, the 'Apps' tab shows [hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/295232) while the 'Script' tab just sorts on score. Is there any reason for this? It would make more sense to use the same criteria for both tabs (other than filtering on [app](/questions/tagged/app) resp. [script](/questions/tagged/script)). I'd prefer the 'hot' one since it emphasizes new and potentially interesting questions, just like the homepages on other sites in the network.